# py2exe giving "import error: no module named py2exe"

Tags: python, py2exe

So when I run the following code in the command prompt:

```
python c:\users\[user]\desktop\setup.py py2exe
```

I receive the following error:

import error: no module named py2exe

Now, after some research, I found that previous users having this issue attempted to use the wrong compatibility with py2exe - using a newer py2exe on an older version of python, for example.

So I checked mine. Nope, Python 2.7. Checked Python name in programs list - Python 2.7.

However, when I typed "python --version" into the command prompt, it returns "2.5.2". So I uninstalled the 2.7 py2exe, installed the 2.5 one, but... same error.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What does your environment path look like? It may contain a reference to an older version of Python. Have you installed any new programs lately?

Comment: Not really - I've uninstalled a fair few, but I haven't installed any new programs, and this is the first version of Python I've worked with

Comment: Well, regardless, could you edit your question to include what appears if you type in `echo %PATH%` from the command line?